# Number theory gcd

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing

If gcd$(a,c) = 1$ and $b\mid c$, prove that $\gcd(a,b)=1$.

I just need someone to check my proof. My proof is as follows:

Proof:
Assume $\gcd(a,c)=1$ and $b\mid c$. Then we know that $c = bk$ and by theorem $ax+cy=1$; $k,x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$. By substitution we obtain,

$ax+bky=1$

$ax+bp=1$, $p=ky$ is an integer.

Thus, $\gcd(a,b)=1$.

Comment: Where do you have a doubt?

Comment: My doubts are in my writing it up. If I should format it differently  ?

Comment: To be honest it sounds like someone citing the rules from a book without understand them at all.  But... the proof is absolutely correct.  My question for you is do you *understand* anything that you just wrote.

Comment: You could be more precise; "by theorem"..which one exactly? Also, look for alternative proofs at MSE yourself.

Comment: You say $a = bk$ and $ax+cy=1$ and $k,x,y$ are integers.  Which integers?  Obvious $ax + cy$ can't equal $1$ for *all* integers.  And obviously $a$ doesn't equal $bk$ for all possible $k$.  So tell my in your words, what you think that means.

Comment: Hears a question for you:  If $ax + by = 7$ does that mean that $\gcd(a,b) = 7$.  Why or why not?

Comment: Your proof is fine, although you say "Assume" where you could better say "Given" and you really ought to say what theorem you're using there. For a more descriptive (not better) proof, you could observe that since $a$ and $c$ are co-prime, they have no common prime factors. Since $b$ divides $c$, every prime factor of $b$ is also a prime factor of $c$ and therefore $a$ and $b$ also have no common prime factors.

Comment: The theorem in my books are numbered and in my notes he didn't number the theorems either. So I'm not sure if I should number the theorem or not. Yes, I understand that if the gcd(a,b)=1 then it can written as a linear combination in the form ax+by=1. k is an integer but b cannot equal 0 and a,b can be integers but both cant be 0.

Comment: You could also point out that  if $b|c$ than any divisor $d$ of $b$ is also a divisor of $c.$ For if  $e\in \Bbb Z$ with $b=de$ and $f\in \Bbb Z$ with $c=fb$ then $c=fb=f(de)=gd$ where $g=fe\in \Bbb Z.$...Therefore for any $d\in \Bbb Z$ we have $(d|a\land d|b)\implies (d|a\land d|c)\implies d\leq \gcd (a,c)=1.$

Comment: Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given is the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is correct, the theorem which you are referring to is [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) which guarantees that if $\gcd(a,b)=d$ then exist $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that

$$ax+by=d$$

and also that if we can find $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $$ax+by=1$$

then $\gcd(a,b)=1$.